# Why does JS code render faster on website than react-native?

Tags: react-native

This is a bit of a general question, but perhaps someone can guide me in the right direction.

I'm using a JS library called Vexflow to render music notes. I uploaded some script to my website AND used the same code to build a React Native app.
When comparing both on the same device (Xiaomi A3), the code renders much faster on my website.
Any ideas why?

Cheers,
Nitzan

Comment: Because in native, JS is converted to native code (java byte code or swift for iOS), which takes time